# Where would I ask about home video/projector setup?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

Which SE community would be suitable to ask questions about home video and projector setups, as well as related wiring?

Answer (score 5):

I would ask on Super User.

Actually, there is already a lot of projector tagged questions there.

Just be sure it's not a duplicate and it’s well written with enough details.

Comment: Yes, [SU + DIY](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bhome-theater%5D+is%3Aquestion), even Ubuntu if it's computer related and Arcade if it's video game projection.

Comment: If its plugged into a computer, the tech sites might work

Answer (score 3):

For shopping-related questions regarding home video and projector setups: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/projector

For some questions regarding how to use  home video and projectors:
https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/projector